# NSPredicate on NSArray of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Imagine you have the following structure for an NSArray of NSDictionary objects:

```
#define kFlameText @"text"
#define kFlameRelation @"relation"


NSArray* data = @[@{kFlameText:@"TextFlame1", kFlameRelation:@"Relation1"}, @{kFlameText:@"TextFlame2", kFlameRelation:@"Relation2"}, @{kFlameText:@"TextFlame3", kFlameRelation:@"Relation3"}}
```

You want to use a `NSPredicate` to extract the dictionary located in second position in your `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` based on the `NSString` `@"Relation2"`

You tried multiple times, with you last attempt being:

```
NSPredicate* sortFlames = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", @"Relation2"];
```

But you are still not there, you still get the following error message:

[image: Error message while testing NSPredicate]

How would you make it work?

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", kFlameRelation, @"Relation2"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate should do the trick:

```
NSPredicate *sortFlames = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", kFlameRelation, @"Relation2"];
```

The `%K` is for the dynamic property name, more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW3).